# I am loading image to tab3 but when sliding my tab recycle view items increased when I come back to first tab

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, tabs

I have also try to change setHasFixsize(true) but it is not working 
problem is when I am com to my own tab then item of tab is increase double times
triple times etc
There is activity that content fragment mtabfragment I have create three fragment java file to three tab layout and connect with these three activity

```
`public class NewsFeeds extends Fragment {

DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

RecyclerView recyclerView;


RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;


ProgressDialog progressDialog;


List<ImageUploadInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();


Context context,contextpuja ;
GridView gridViewPuja,gridViewAll,gridViewC;
View view;

public NewsFeeds() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = getActivity();

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feeds2,container, false);

    return view;
}



@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = getActivity();
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragmentActivity);

    recyclerView =  view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());


    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Images From Firebase.");

     progressDialog.show();


    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Main2Activity.FB_Database_Path);


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = postSnapshot.getValue(ImageUploadInfo.class);

                list.add(imageUploadInfo);
            }

            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), list);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                          progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });








}
```

}

Comment: do list.clear();

Comment: I apply list.clear(); code before return view and it's working

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: Thanks your answer is perfect but in that position code is not working I have changed it to mention location in code and it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized your list at the start. So after every api call new items gets added to it. To avoid that, you add this line 
**list.clear();**
before this line
adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), list);
or Do not initialize your list before. put new ArrayList(); inside onDataChange method.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way 
create a method inside your RecyclerViewAdapter class like setData(pass your list) and set data to list in your RecyclerViewAdapter class;

```
public class NewsFeeds extends Fragment {

DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

RecyclerView recyclerView;


RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;


ProgressDialog progressDialog;


List<ImageUploadInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();


Context context,contextpuja ;
GridView gridViewPuja,gridViewAll,gridViewC;
View view;

public NewsFeeds() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = getActivity();

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feeds2,container, false);
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), list);

    return view;
}



@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = getActivity();
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragmentActivity);

    recyclerView =  view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());


    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Images From Firebase.");

     progressDialog.show();


    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Main2Activity.FB_Database_Path);


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = 
                 postSnapshot.getValue(ImageUploadInfo.class);

              list.add(imageUploadInfo);
            }


             adpter.setData(list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

         progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                          progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
```

Comment: public void setData(List<ImageUploadInfo> imageUploadInfo) {
    this.imageUploadInfo= imageUploadInfo;
}

Answer (score 0):

I have just add code by the use of code **list.clear()** before ***return view*** and get perfect output

```
public class NewsFeeds extends Fragment {

DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

RecyclerView recyclerView;


RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;


ProgressDialog progressDialog;


List<ImageUploadInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();


Context context,contextpuja ;
GridView gridViewPuja,gridViewAll,gridViewC;
View view;

public NewsFeeds() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = getActivity();

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feeds2,container, false);

    //-----list.clear()-----use to fix bug ----------------
    list.clear();
    return view;
}
```